# how to acces DVWA login page from Python Socket

Tags: python, penetration-testing

I want to create a HTTP call with sockets to localhost//dvwa/login.php. Similar scenario as if i want for www.google.com how can i point to localhost/dvwa/login.php ? Below is my Code and error .I will be thank Full.

```
import socket
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
target ="localhost//dvwa//login.php" #input("Enter URL:")"attack.samsclass.info"
s.connect((target,80))
#s.send(r"GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost:{}\n\n".format(target).encode())
print(s.recv(1024))
s.close()
```

[image: This image shows the complete errorp]

Answer (score 0):

Following code snippet may help you:

```
import socket
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
target ="localhost"
s.connect((target,80))
s.send(b"GET /dvwa/login.php HTTP/1.1\nHost:{}\n\n".format(target).encode())
print(s.recv(1024).decode())
s.close()
```